# Error deploying landscape

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I am deploying OpenStack with Autopilot and I failed more than 10 times on the Landscape installation step. My MAAS sever and nodes all have 2 NICs,and can connect the Internet.

This is the error message on the node machine /var/log/juju/unit-landscape-server-0.log , every time the landscape installation stop here, please help, I have cost time on this nearly one month, thanks very much.

This is the error on the log, shows that we could not connect to keyserver.ubuntu.com.

[image: error message]

But if we run the command manually, it could work very well.

[image: manually run command]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer, but I suspect connection issues from your original paste.  So I'll just answer with some general troubleshooting tips.  Let's check it out.  Update your answer with more details as you find them.

### Back off to just Juju and MAAS

Follow the setup [instructions](https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.25/config-maas) (you can even do this on your maas server).

Then:

```
juju switch <maas_environment>
juju bootstrap -v
juju deploy cs:trusty/ubuntu
juju add-unit -n <number of unused machines> ubuntu
```

Make sure everything comes up OK.

### Try fetching the key across all machines with juju run

```
juju run --all '<that sudo apt-key command>'
```

My suspicion is one machine or more will fail, and you can troubleshoot network connectivity from there.